# Powerline Fonts Not coming in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed Powerline10k in my zsh (Ubuntu). But the fonts are not coming up in VSCode.
It was coming up previously but after syncing VScode with my Windows, I think the settings are messed up probably.

As you can see the fonts are loaded but the symbols aren't.
[image: My Vscode Terminal]

My settings.json in VSCode.

[image]

I have installed the Menlo font as well:

[image]

I tried changing the font to Meslo Same issue. Cleared font cache with:

```
 sudo fc-cache -vf /usr/share/fonts
```

Still same issue.

Reconfigured p10k with p10 configure. Problem still persists.

Am I missing something?

Menlo Exists:

```
fc-list | grep -i "Menlo"


/home/sss/.fonts/Menlo Italic for Powerline.ttf: Menlo for Powerline:style=Italic
/home/sss/.local/share/fonts/Menlo Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Menlo for Powerline:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/Menlo-for-Powerline/Menlo for Powerline.ttf: Menlo for Powerline:style=Regular
/home/sss/.fonts/Menlo Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Menlo for Powerline:style=Bold Italic
/home/sss/.fonts/Menlo for Powerline.ttf: Menlo for Powerline:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/Menlo-for-Powerline/Menlo Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf: Menlo for Powerline:style=Bold Italic
/home/sss/.local/share/fonts/Menlo Bold for Powerline.ttf: Menlo for Powerline:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/Menlo-for-Powerline/Menlo Bold for Powerline.ttf: Menlo for Powerline:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/Menlo-for-Powerline/Menlo Italic for Powerline.ttf: Menlo for Powerline:style=Italic
/home/sss/.fonts/Menlo Bold for Powerline.ttf: Menlo for Powerline:style=Bold
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience you don't need the additional single quotes for a font, which has whitespaces.
e.g. you can just do:

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Menlo for Powerline"
```

instead of:

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'Menlo for Powerline'"
```

Comment: Yeah, Have tried that as well. Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

VScode 1.70 (July 2022) should include [`xterm.js` 5.0 beta](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js), which fixes a lot of issues regarding font rendering, as listed in [VSCode PR 156993](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/156993).

For instance, "[Support semi-circle powerline symbols](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/154324)", fixed in [PR 154557](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/154557), is released in [VSCode insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) today.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2193314/177672234-85039a8c-172f-4882-b15d-9c09813a37c3.png]

See [Rendering improvments](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_70.md#rendering-improvements)

> Semi-circle Powerline symbols are now custom rendered.
>
> Like the arrow symbols in the previous release, these should blend seamlessly with adjacent cells and extend to the height of the cell even when line height is used.
>
> [image: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/raw/vnext/release-notes/images/1_70/terminal-semi-circle.png]